# C : Catch Process Termination for other system processes

Tags: c, winapi, process, signals, exit

I need to catch process termination signals for child processes.

So for example, if my Win32 console application spawns a notepad process and the user closes notepad, I would like to detect that.

I don't want to block (asynchronous model)

I'm creating a process using the win api [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How are you spawning it, and are you modal. Ie if notepad is up can you still do things on the console app.

Comment: Did you try `WaitForSingleObject` ?

Comment: WaitForSingleObject would block. correct?

Comment: Not when it's `dwMilliseconds` parameter is set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `WaitForSingleObject()` with it's `dwMilliseconds` parameter as 0? `WaitForSingleObject()` will return immediately if `dwMilliseconds` is 0 and will return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` if the process isn't dead or `WAIT_OBJECT_0` if it is.
Example, assuming the child process handle is `hProcess`:

```
DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 0);
if (result == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    /* Process not dead */;
else if (result == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    /* Process dead */;
else
    /* Error occured */;
```

And alternative is `GetExitCodeProcess()`. The "exit code" returned by it will be `STILL_ACTIVE` if it is still running, otherwise it will return the actual exit code.
Example, again assuming the child process handle is `hProcess`:

```
DWORD exitCode;
if (!GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exitCode))
    /* Error occured */;
else if (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
    /* Process is still running */
else
    /* exitCode now contains the process exit code, and the process is not running anymore */;
```

Both these examples are non-blocking

Answer (score 2):

Use [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202783.aspx) from a new thread.

See [Waiting for a Process to Terminate](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=362660&seqNum=7)

Comment: +1 for suggesting a mechanism that stands a chance of generating an asynchronous notification without a core-eating CPU loop.